# take a single picture

Tags: android, android-camera

there is a simple tutorial to take a picture with android (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html) which I followed.

```
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
protected void onTakePicture()
{
    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application    
    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);    
    // create a file to save the image    
    File file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    String path = file.getAbsolutePath() + "/Android/data/com.myapplication/files";
    File dir = new File(path);
    if (!dir.isDirectory())
        dir.mkdirs();
    File outFile = new File(path + File.separator + "img.jpg");
    Uri fileUri = Uri.fromFile(outFile);
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri); 
    // set the image file name    
    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);        
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode==CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE)
    {
         // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
        Uri fn = data.getData();
        Toast.makeText(this, "Image saved to:\n" + fn.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

I am calling this from within an activity. The problem now is that when the camera activity appears, I can take multiple pictures, but I only want to take a single picture and then return to the calling activity. onActivityResult will not be called until I leave the camera activity (by pressing the "back" button). Then the data.getData() crashes.

Any ideas?

Thank you
Gerhard

Comment: Did you try this instead,     Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);

Comment: I tried, but no difference...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm ... this works for me to capture the image:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
activity.startActivityForResult(intent, AbstractActivity.CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```

when the user takes the picture, it asks whether the user wants to accept this image, and then it goes back to my activity where I ...

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            handleAvatarUpload(data); // which uses Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
        } 
    }
}
```

I haven't received any crash reports with this code and it's been out in the wild for a few months. our userbase is in line with other apps in our category with android 2.3.3 at around 71% of users, 2.2 at 16.35%, and 2.1 at 5.7%

Comment: Thanks, this led me to press the small "paper clip" symbol after taking the picture, which appears after I have taken the picture. Then the camera activity returns to my activity and the data.GetData() doesn't crash. Still the Uri isn't the one I did choose, but then I can copy the file.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question but I ran into the same problem.

For me it was fixed by not providing a URI but the URI path `myUri.getPath()`

The following should do what you want:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri.getPath());
startActivityForResult(intent, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
```